# Do not install recommended packages of dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

Recommended packages of a package and recommended packages of it's dependencies are installed by default when installing a package (tested on Ubuntu 18.04 Beta).

How to install recommended packages of a package, but skip recommended packages of it's dependencies by a single `apt` command?

Comment: The `--(no-)install-{recommends,suggests}` flags are set for the entire apt operation, so your best bet would be (a) either installing without recommends and then installing the recommends, or (b) parsing out the recommends and installing them explicitl. Both are covered in ...

Comment: (It might be possible to use `aptitude`'s filter given there for an easier single command operation: `aptitude install --without-recommends foo ~Rrecommends:foo`, though I haven't tested it.)

Comment: This will work although it's two apt commands instead of a single apt command. If anyone want to combine the two commands into a one-line command, please comment here and post the one-liner in the comment so that I can try it. Then I will either reopen this question, so that you can post an answer to it or post another comment if your suggested answer failed for some reason. Remember some dependency packages may already be installed.